# How to handle error when processing message sent to EventHub?

Tags: azure-eventhub

I am considering using Microsoft EventHub to transfer our transaction data to our reporting database. The initial investigation leads me to consider sending messages from transaction application each time a database record is added, changed or deleted. This is fairly straight forward using the entity framework plumbing.

After sending these messages to the EventHub we can define an Azure Function App that triggers using the EventHubTrigger attribute to process the messages on demand as and when they arrive. This is perfect for what we need as the messages will be in a guaranteed sequence which we need to ensure data integrity when building the report data warehouse.

However, what happens if an error occurs e.g. a coding error of some description the messages will keep coming in and the function app method will continue to be triggered and all subsequent messages sent are at risk of failure due to the error'd message?

Ideally you'd want the triggering to cease until a fix had been applied and then allow it to restart from the checkpoint. But how do you manage and control that process?

Comment: *This is perfect for what we need as the messages will be in a guaranteed sequence* How so? message ordering is not available unless a specific partition key is used but that degrades the availability. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-availability-and-consistency?tabs=dotnet#consistency. Have you considered a queue?

Comment: Hi @PeterBons thank you for your response, we intended to use a partition key yes. We are currently using message queues but these cause problems due to messages being executed out of sequence which we've solved by setting the retry to 5 which then eventually sorts itself out but doesn't seem very elegant.

Comment: @PeterBons do you mean a Service Bus Queue specifically?

Comment: Yes, or a storage queue. How much messages do you expect and what size?

Comment: We currently use a storage queue however these aren't guaranteed to process in sequence from what I've read here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted

Comment: Ah yes you are right, forgot the ordering, you will need to use the azure service bus queue

Comment: I think the EventHub does use a service bus behind the scenes and as it is designed for data ingestion and egress it seemed like the obvious choice. However, I'll go and investigate service bus separately as using these services raises all sorts of challenges during local development which is another pain in the butt to be resolved!! Thanks for your reply though doesn't seem to be a subject area with a great deal of available dev knowledge! I can't even find a book on it :/